# How to set a Tooltip for Jquery Dialog heading in asp.net

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have created a jQuery dialog in as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.divid').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        draggable: true,
        width: 720,
        height: 560,
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        title: "My Title",
        open: function (type, data) {
            $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
        }
    });
});
```

I need to add a tooltip for the dialog title (set as "My Title" in this example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$('.divid').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    draggable: true,
    width: 720,
    height: 560,
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    title: "My Title",
    open: function (type, data) {
        $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
    }
}).siblings('.ui-dialog-titlebar')
  .find('.ui-dialog-title')
  .prop('title', $('.divid').dialog("option", "title"));
```

**[Working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/CqPGm/)**